# runtime error -2147319767 (80028029) issue

Tags: vba

I know there have been a few questions on this - but i have tried the suggestions and it doesnt seem to work for me.

I get this issue on the offendind line.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Live_Tracker
Set Live_Tracker = Worksheets("Live_Tracker")
Dim WIP
Set WIP = Worksheets("WIP")
Dim WR_FF
Set WR_FF = Worksheets("WR_FF")
Dim Historic
Set Historic = Worksheets("Historic")
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim LastrowLive As Integer
Dim x_track, x_wip As Double
Dim xt As Boolean
Dim count As Integer

'---------------------PASSWORD PROTECT----------------------------------
Dim MyPassword As Variant
Dim Password As String
Password = 123

MyPassword = Application.InputBox("Password Required to Run this Macro", "Password Required to Run this Macro")

If MyPassword = Password Then
Range("A1").Value = "This is a VBA Project Password Enabler"
Else
MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
End If

'____MAIN CODE______________________________________________________________


Lastrow = WIP.Cells(WIP.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row <<<<<<<< THIS LINE>>>>>>>>>>>
LastrowLive = Live_Tracker.Cells(Live_Tracker.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

x_track = LastrowLive + 1
x_wip = 2
```

Comment: For row counters use Long instead of integer.  Integer max value is about 32k.

Comment: ...also it's useful to share the *text* of the error message: we haven't memorized them all.

Comment: It says Run time error -2147319767 (80028029)

Comment: Automation error - Invalid Forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type

Comment: I cut and pasted the code and now it works - nothing else changed

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Comment: Your password should be `"123"` if it's a string